# Irregular nest tidyverse

Tags: r, nested, tidyr

I have following problem. I want to nest time series by date but include x amount of earlier dates to nest as well. little example will clear this one:

lets create sample tbl:

```
set.seed(13)
tibble(date = c(rep("2018-01-31", 3), rep("2018-02-28", 3), rep("2018-03-31", 3), rep("2018-04-30", 3)),
       form = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 4),
       value = rnorm(n = 12),
       ind = runif(12)) -> tbl
```

And lets nest it:

```
tbl %>% 
  nest(-date)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  date       data            
  <chr>      <list>          
1 2018-01-31 <tibble [3 x 3]>
2 2018-02-28 <tibble [3 x 3]>
3 2018-03-31 <tibble [3 x 3]>
4 2018-04-30 <tibble [3 x 3]>
```

I love this format of data structure (I hate normal lists). I would like to have following:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  date       data            
  <chr>      <list>          
1 2018-01-31 <NA>
2 2018-02-28 <tibble [6 x 3]>
3 2018-03-31 <tibble [6 x 3]>
4 2018-04-30 <tibble [6 x 3]>
```

Where data in row 2018-02-28 would include Jan and Feb data and row 2018-03-31 would include Feb and Mar data and so on. Flexible solution, so I can say how many previous periods to include would be great result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario of two is relatively easy, by binding tables:

```
tbl %>% 
  nest(-date) %>% 
  mutate(data2 = map2(data, lag(data), ~safely(bind_rows, otherwise = NA)(.y, .x)$result))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
>   date       data             data2           
>   <chr>      <list>           <list>          
> 1 2018-01-31 <tibble [3 x 3]> <lgl [1]>       
> 2 2018-02-28 <tibble [3 x 3]> <tibble [6 x 3]>
> 3 2018-03-31 <tibble [3 x 3]> <tibble [6 x 3]>
> 4 2018-04-30 <tibble [3 x 3]> <tibble [6 x 3]>
> ```

Comment: gave me idea of tibbletime and rollify, could we wrap bind_rows in rolling function and do that way x periods? Thanks for answer, will wait a bit to see if we get multiperiod answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea, seems to be working. Thanks to Axeman, giving me this idea.

helper function:

```
bind_roll <- rollify(~dplyr::bind_rows(.), window = 3, unlist = FALSE)

tbl %>% 
  nest(-date) %>% 
  mutate(data2 = bind_roll(data))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  date       data             data2           
  <chr>      <list>           <list>          
1 2018-01-31 <tibble [3 x 3]> <lgl [1]>       
2 2018-02-28 <tibble [3 x 3]> <lgl [1]>       
3 2018-03-31 <tibble [3 x 3]> <tibble [9 x 3]>
4 2018-04-30 <tibble [3 x 3]> <tibble [9 x 3]>
```

Comment: Excellent, I think this is very natural solution to this issue.